# iphone - how do I make my label look like iPhone's inbuilt ones?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I want to create custom labels using UILabel that look like the ones iPhone settings have. Something similar to [image: the one here]

How do I create the shadow effect and what font could I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the shadowOffset to your UILabel. the first parameter is for horizontal shadow and second parameter for vertical shadow(as you are showing white shadow in your image).

```
label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
```